# How can I get an email message's text content using Python?

Tags: python, email, mime, rfc822

Given an RFC822 message in Python 2.6, how can I get the *right* text/plain content part?  Basically, the algorithm I want is this:

```
message = email.message_from_string(raw_message)
if has_mime_part(message, "text/plain"):
    mime_part = get_mime_part(message, "text/plain")
    text_content = decode_mime_part(mime_part)
elif has_mime_part(message, "text/html"):
    mime_part = get_mime_part(message, "text/html")
    html = decode_mime_part(mime_part)
    text_content = render_html_to_plaintext(html)
else:
    # fallback
    text_content = str(message)
return text_content
```

Of these things, I have `get_mime_part` and `has_mime_part` down pat, but I'm not quite sure how to get the decoded text from the MIME part.  I can get the *encoded* text using `get_payload()`, but if I try to use the `decode` parameter of the `get_payload()` method (see [the doc](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload)) I get an error when I call it on the text/plain part:

> ```
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/
> email/message.py", line 189, in get_payload
>     raise TypeError('Expected list, got %s' % type(self._payload))
> TypeError: Expected list, got <type 'str'>
> ```

In addition, I don't know how to take HTML and render it to text as closely as possible.

Comment: I found a useful solution to something similar in http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/11/19/parsing-multilingual-email-with-python/

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In a multipart e-mail, `email.message.Message.get_payload()` returns a list with one item for each part. The easiest way is to walk the message and get the payload on each part:

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_message)
for part in msg.walk():
    # each part is a either non-multipart, or another multipart message
    # that contains further parts... Message is organized like a tree
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
        print part.get_payload() # prints the raw text
```

For a non-multipart message, no need to do all the walking. You can go straight to get_payload(), regardless of content_type.

```
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_message)
msg.get_payload()
```

If the content is encoded, you need to pass `None` as the first parameter to `get_payload()`, followed by True (the decode flag is the second parameter). For example, suppose that my e-mail contains an MS Word document attachment:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_message)
for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'application/msword':
        name = part.get_param('name') or 'MyDoc.doc'
        f = open(name, 'wb')
        f.write(part.get_payload(None, True)) # You need None as the first param
                                              # because part.is_multipart() 
                                              # is False
        f.close()
```

As for getting a reasonable plain-text approximation of an HTML part, I've found that [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) works pretty darn well.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation...that covers exactly what I've already got; I can, as noted, locate and extract the bare payload of the part.  However, I can _not_ decode the part if it's decoded, nor can I render the text/html part to text if no text/plain part is available.

Comment: (on re-read -- sorry, coffee is lacking!) Well, okay, so you've solved my HTML to text problem :)

Comment: My bad... clearly not enough coffee last night when I answered. I've amended the answer, hopefully with what you need.

Comment: Cool.. How can I check if the part is encoded?  Where do I see the part's Content-Transfer-Encoding attribute?

Comment: Use part.get_param('content-transfer-encoding') to see the attribute

Comment: Actually, use part.get("content-transfer-encoding"), since it's just a header.  Not part of the content-type header.  Also, instead of `part.get_payload(None, True)` you can use `part.get_payload(decode=True)`, which I think is a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Flat is better than nested ;)

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
assert isinstance(msg, MIMEMultipart)

for _ in [k.get_payload() for k in msg.walk() if k.get_content_type() == 'text/plain']:
    print _
```

Comment: This blindly extracts all `text/plain´ parts with no attention to which one is "right".

Comment: @tripleee Generally we use one plain, one html part, and several image parts. Even if  there is more than plain parts, how do you know which one right?

Comment: In the typical case, with a toplevel `multipart/alternative` where only one part is `text/plain`, that one.  In the more general case, I don't think there is a single right answer, because it depends on the purpose of your application and the preferences of the recipient.

Comment: In all fairness, the accepted answer has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try my lib for IMAP: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

# Get date, subject and body len of all emails from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch():
        print(msg.date, msg.subject, len(msg.text or msg.html))
```

See html2text: https://pypi.org/project/html2text/.

And may be msg.text is enough

Answer (score 0):

To add on @Jarret Hardie's excellent answer:

I personally like to transform that kind of data structures to a dictionary that I can reuse later, so something like this where the `content_type` is the key and the `payload` is the value:

```py
import email

[...]

email_message = {
    part.get_content_type(): part.get_payload()
    for part in email.message_from_bytes(raw_email).walk()
}

print(email_message["text/plain"])
```

Answer (score 0):

#This is what I have for a gmail account using the app password method.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox
import email
my_email = "your email"
my_pass = "app password"
mailbox =  MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login(my_email, my_pass)

for msg in mailbox.fetch('Subject "   "', charset='utf8'):
    print("Message id:",msg.uid)
    print("Message Subject:",msg.subject)
    print("Message Date:", msg.date)
    print("Message Text:", msg.text)
```