# How do I only print out the message instead of the whole text

Tags: python, imap, mail-server

This is my Python code to read an email:

```
import imaplib

mailserver=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
user = 'm****l@gmail.com'
passs = 'm****s'
mailserver.login(user,passs)

status, count = mailserver.select('Inbox')
status, data = mailserver.fetch(count[0],'(UID BODY[TEXT])')

print(data)

mailserver.close()
mailserver.logout()
```

It prints out the whole html portion of the message. How do I only print out the message itself?

Comment: Walk the message object tree - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463074/how-can-i-get-an-email-messages-text-content-using-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import imaplib

mailserver=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
user = 'm****l@gmail.com'
passs = 'm****s'
mailserver.login(user,passs)

status, count = mailserver.select('Inbox')
status, data = mailserver.fetch(count[0],'(RFC822)')

print(data)

# Something like this
import email
msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
print(msg['Subject'], msg['Body'])

mailserver.close()
mailserver.logout()
```

I posted a self reminder in a gist if you are curious.

https://gist.github.com/jmunsch/11374042

Comment: This is wrong. Using hardcoded offsets will fail, sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I didn't know that ... I think the docs might need some expanding .... https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [How can I get an email message's text content using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463074/how-can-i-get-an-email-messages-text-content-using-python) (among a ton of others). In short, you have to take a look at the MIME tree and find out which of these parts is interesting for you. Using a unversal offset like [1] will *not* work.