# Python IMAP from GMAIL encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding, imap

I'm trying to make an IMAP connector in Python to retrieve mail before processed them. For now I do my test with GMAIL.

Here is the mail I'm trying to process : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrb1C.png

In my code here is what I do for now :

```
import email
import chardet
import imaplib
for mail_id in data:
    res, data = self.conn.fetch(mail_id, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)] BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (TO)] UID BODY[TEXT])')
    raw_body = data[0][1]
    encoding_body = chardet.detect(raw_body)['encoding']
    body = email.message_from_string(raw_body.decode(encoding_body))
    dest_email = data[1][1]
    sender_email = data[2][1]

    f = open('/home/nathan/PycharmProjects/test.html', 'w+')
    f.write(body.get_payload())
    f.close()
```

I didn't have any error but here is the result of the body :

https://pastebin.com/fhzqsCRM

Any idea why some weird char are here ? Also, the char with accent aren't correctly decoded..

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

I already try with the following :

```
res, data = self.conn.fetch(mail_id, '(RFC822)')
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
        print(part)
```

I just have the HTML, but same issue with encoding..

FINAL EDIT :

Thanks to @Botje it appears that the e-mail was encoded with 'Quoted-printable'. So here is the solution for that type of encoding :

```
import quopri
res, data = self.conn.fetch(mail_id, '(RFC822)')
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
        part = quopri.decodestring(part.get_payload()).decode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get an email message's text content using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463074/how-can-i-get-an-email-messages-text-content-using-python)

Comment: Use message_from_bytes, and fetch the whole BODY[] or RFC822 so you get the headers so the decoder can work properly.

Comment: @Max I edit my question with a new test, I just have the HTML now but still encoding issue..

Comment: Note the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` part.

Comment: Thanks @Botj, that was the issue !

Comment: Try to use high level lib https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/